# Display Image from QCamera in Label

Tags: c++, qt, camera, rotation, qlabel

I am writing a program, to display two cameras next to each other. In Qt it is pretty simple with the QCamera. But my Cameras are turned by 90°, so I have to turn the Camera in the porgram too.

The QCamera variable has no command to turn it, so I want to display it in a label, and not in a viewfinder. So I take an Image, turn it and display it in a label.

```
QImage img;
QPixmap img_;
img = ui->viewfinder->grab().toImage();
img_ = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
img_ = img_.transformed(QTransform().rotate((90)%360));
QImage img2;
QPixmap img2_;
img2 = ui->viewfinder->grab().toImage();
img2_ = QPixmap::fromImage(img2);
img2_ = img2_.transformed(QTransform().rotate((90)%360));
ui->label->setPixmap(img_);
ui->label_2->setPixmap(img2_);
```

When I start the program there are just two black boxes next to each other.
(In the code there is missing the part where I deklare it, but the camera works fine in the viewfinder so I think there is no problem)

Comment: What makes you think the images would refresh themselves automatically ? I'm going to assume `grab().toImage()` takes a snapshot. Since you do it at the beginning of your application, maybe the image given by your camera is just a black background ?

Comment: The fact that I get no Image in the label makes me think that. I can see the camera image in the viewfinder, when I switch back to the viewfinder with a stackedwidget which is changing on button pressed

Comment: When are you calling the code you posted ? can't you call that code on button pressed ?

Comment: @FélixCantournet I tried it already, but it won't work too. I call it on programm start

Comment: What do you want to use the QCamera for ? viewfinding, video capture or photo ?

Comment: @FélixCantournet I want to have a life picture. But because the cameras are mounted 90° turned i want to rotate the video stream.

Comment: Btw. It should not make a difference but from [the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) it looks like `grab()` already returns a `QPixmap` which you could use directly instead of creating a `QImage` which you then transform back to a `QPixmap`

Comment: @Bowdzone it works, but like you said doesn't make any differnce

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`img_ = QPixmap::grabWindow(ui->viewfinder->winId(), 0, 0, -1, -1);` (for take a snapshot as QPixmap)
or
`img = QPixmap::grabWindow(ui->viewfinder->winId(), 0, 0, -1, -1).toImage();` (for take a snapshot as QImage)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the orientation of the camera to correct the image orientation in view finder as described in Qt documentation. Here is the link:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cameraoverview.html

and here is the code found in the documentation:

```
// Assuming a QImage has been created from the QVideoFrame that needs to be presented
QImage videoFrame;
QCameraInfo cameraInfo(camera); // needed to get the camera sensor position and orientation

// Get the current display orientation
const QScreen *screen = QGuiApplication::primaryScreen();
const int screenAngle = screen->angleBetween(screen->nativeOrientation(), screen->orientation());

int rotation;
if (cameraInfo.position() == QCamera::BackFace) {
    rotation = (cameraInfo.orientation() - screenAngle) % 360;
} else {
    // Front position, compensate the mirror
    rotation = (360 - cameraInfo.orientation() + screenAngle) % 360;
}

// Rotate the frame so it always shows in the correct orientation
videoFrame = videoFrame.transformed(QTransform().rotate(rotation));
```

It looks like you don't even understand, what you are looking at...
Whats the purpose of pasting stuff like that to forum? Did you read ALL description about this? Its only part of the code that - i see You dont understand, but you try to be smart :)

Comment: Sorry, that helps nothing at all!